# Sendmail very slow - /etc/hosts configuration

Tags: sendmail

It takes ~15 seconds to send single e-mail using sendmail.

**/var/log/mail.log:**

```
Jul 31 09:52:42 piotr-probook sendmail[2912]: My unqualified host name (piotr-probook) unknown; sleeping for retry
```

**/etc/hostname:**

```
piotr-probook
```

**/etc/hosts:**

```
127.0.0.1   piotr-probook localdev localhost
192.168.1.1 router
```

**/etc/mail/sendmail.cf:**

```
# hosts file (normally /etc/hosts)
O HostsFile=/etc/hosts
```

Obviously I can ping `piotr-probook` host and HTTP server popups in browser when i type url `http://piotr-probook`

What am I doing wrong? How to fix the problem?

Comment: Your question and Problem is unclear. Please add more information about what you're trying to archive and what your Problems are (e.g. How do you use sendmail? In a PHP script? Python? Java? Is Apache involved?). Basically: What are you doing?

Comment: @mondjunge My problem is quite clear. It takes ~15 seconds to send single e-mail using sendmail. I even posted the cause of the issue (see log), and I am just asking how to fix it. I just want to execute `sendmail -t mail.txt`. No PHP, Java, etc. plain sendmail.

Comment: Got the answer: http://superuser.com/a/626219/242163

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Got the answer at superuser.com https://superuser.com/a/626219/242163:

---

Sendmail requires that the result of "hostname" be a fully qualified domain name to start cleanly.

Set the hostname to something like piotr-probook.localdomain and update /etc/hosts.

**/etc/hosts**

```
127.0.0.1   piotr-probook.localdomain piotr-probook localdev localhost
```

Comment: Also make sure you have a resolvable FQDN in /etc/mailname

Comment: in my case `localhost.localdomain` along with `localhoat` and hostname was the missing piece (debian's sendmail inside docker)

Answer (score 16):

The above answer didn't work for me. So I am posting here what I have done to make it work.

Installed `send mail` through `terminal`

```
apt-get install sendmail
```

then opened the `hosts` file

```
# edited from: sudo gedit etc/hosts
sudo gedit /etc/hosts
```

replaced the the line

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
```

with

```
127.0.0.1 localhost localhost.localdomain mydomainname
```

To get the `domain name` please type

```
hostname
```

in `terminal` and run.

restart apache

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Comment: sendmail should not be related to apache

Comment: @Zitrax i didn't get you. Can you please explain what do you mean?

Comment: Your last step restarts apache, I just meant that shouldn't be needed for fixing the sendmail issue.

Comment: The apache restart ins't necessary I'm guessing, since you changed the hosts file and it is independent form apache. Anyway, I might be wrong and restarting apache also does something weird to sendmail, maybe it touches some files used by both Apache and Senmail but I doubt it.